# Getting database information from other file

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 3 different files called: app.js, ServerManager.js and Users.js.

To start everything, I run app.js which runs my ServerManager.

Running ServerManager in App.js:

```
var ServerManager = require('./modules/ServerManager.js');
var serverManager = new ServerManager({
    app: app,
    path: __dirname
});
```

Then serverManager is called and I can do stuff in there, then I'm trying to send stuff to Users.js from ServerManager but it seems like it doesn't work.

ServerManager.js

```
var config = require('../config.js');
var express = require('express');
var colors = require('colors');

var DatabaseManager = require('../modules/DatabaseManager.js');
var RouteManager = require('../modules/RouteManager.js');
var Users = require('../data/users.js');

module.exports = function(options){
    return new ServerManager(options);
}

var ServerManager = function (options) {
    var self = this;
    this.app = options.app;
    this.options = options;

    this.dbManager = new DatabaseManager();
    this.dbManager.use();
    this.RoutesManager = new RouteManager(this.app);
    this.RoutesManager.use();


    this.usersManager = new Users(this);
}

ServerManager.prototype.getDatabase = function () {
    return this.dbManager();
}
```

Users.js - Marked in code what it can't find.

```
module.exports = function (ServerManager) {
    return new Users(ServerManager);
};

var Users = function (ServerManager) {
    var self = this;
    this.serverManager = ServerManager;
};

Users.prototype.createUser = function (username, email, password) {
    this.serverManager.getDatabase(); <--- Can't find getDatabase()
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should change your *Users.js* code to:

```
// This is the Users object
// and this function is its constructor
// that can create users instances
var Users = function (ServerManager) {
    var self = this; this.serverManager = ServerManager;
};

// We define a method for the user object
Users.prototype.createUser = function (username, email, password) {
    this.serverManager.getDatabase();
};

// We export the user object
module.exports = Users;
```

Now the then you do

```
var Users = require('../data/users.js');
```

you get the User object.
And so, you can do `new Users(...)`.

The same thing has to be done for the ServerManager.

If you want to use your code as it is, you don't have to use the `new` keyword on the imported object.

Comment: But I need to use that getDatabase() prototype from ServerManager.js so I couldn't remove that part.

Comment: This is not the hole script, just the first lines.

Comment: Yeah, but if I'm not returning the ServerManager there's no way I can access it other than requiring it there but that would cause calling everything in there multiple times.

Comment: I don't think you understand me.